# Extract xmls from files in ksh

Tags: sed, ksh

I am using the below piece of code to extract request XML from a text file,

This works when the request XML tags are in separate lines, but fails when the complete request is in a single line. Could anybody please help me in handling it?

**My Code snippet**

```
echo "Starting Log Extractor on $(date)"
i=0
Request_Tag=GetXyz

Start_Tag="<"$Request_Tag
End_Tag="<\/"$Request_Tag">"

sed -n "/${Start_Tag}/,/${End_Tag}/p" CmServer.log >ExtractedXmls.txt

exec < ExtractedXmls.txt
j=1
while read array[i]; 
do
    filename=GetXyz_$j.xml
    a=`echo ${array[$i]} | grep -e "$Start_Tag"`
    b=`echo ${array[$i]} | grep -e "$End_Tag"`

    LengthStart=$(expr length "$a")
    LengthEnd=$(expr length "$b")


    if [[ $LengthStart >0 ]]; then
    echo ${array[$i]} >> $filename

    elif [[ $LengthEnd >0 ]]; then
    echo ${array[$i]} >> $filename
    ((j=j+1))

    else
    echo ${array[$i]} >> $filename
    fi
done
```

The input file has texts like below ,

```
[Thread-4]  08/02/2016 04:39:30:510 DEBUG clyde.q.msgdetail:trace:? - Got msg from queue in QServerImpl
<GetXyz><MsgProtocol>SCIP</MsgProtocol>...........</GetXyz>

[Thread-4]  08/02/2016 04:39:30:510 DEBUG clyde.q.msgdetail:trace:? - Got msg from queue in QServerImpl
<GetXyz>
<MsgProtocol>SCIP</MsgProtocol>
.
.
.
</GetXyz>
```

Comment: I am new to shell scripting , so do not have much idea on thee utilities . Will this help extracting xmls from text files? if yes , do you have any examples ?

Comment: Increment `i` somewhere in the loop? Maybe?

Comment: I don't think that would help.

Comment: Sorry  ..I guess I did not draft my question properly , by handling I meant I need to extract those xmls in single line as well , which are currently failing with the above code snippet.

Comment: Are you using this to extract XML from a file with non-XML text, or is the whole file XML?  If it's a particular node in an XML file, I would not use `sed` to parse it out. An example input file would be greatly appreciated. Please update the question.

Comment: If you have `xmllint` (it's part of `libxml2-utils` on Debian based systems; `libxml2` on RedHat based) then you can do `xmllint --format - < cmServer.log | sed -n "/${Start_Tag}/,/${End_Tag}/p" > ExtractedXmls.txt`; the `xmllint` will ensure that each tag is on its own line and split up single-line entries into multiple lines.

Comment: With XMLStarlet: `xml sel -t -c '//tag'` or something similar.

Comment: I feel these are utilities to work with xml files. As asked for,  I have added the structure of my input file in the question

Comment: Any special output format required? Or just the XML in any form?

Answer (score 1):

Assumption:

- The input file contains XML on lines not starting with `[Thread`.

Solution:

- Remove the lines starting with `[Thread`.

This does that, and also removes empty lines:

```
sed -e '/^\[Thread/d' -e '^$d' input.txt >output.xml
```

If the start tag may start somewhere on the `[Thread` line, delete everything up to a `<` on that line:

```
sed -e 's/^\[Thread[^<]*//' -e '^$d' input.txt >output.xml
```

Comment: sorry Kusal , but the input file contains request xml even on the lines starting with  thread

Comment: @AbhinavSingh See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use two different rules to match the two cases:

```
 sed -n '/GetXyz/{ /\/GetXyz/ {p;n} }; /GetXyz/, /\/GetXyz/p'
```

If the line matches both `GetXyz` and `/GetXyz`, print it and continue with the next line. If the line matches only `GetXyz`, use it as the beginning of an interval to print.